# CrossWalk / Cordova build in INTEL XDK gives parsing error on older android OS releases

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I'm wanting to us the CrossWalk build with INTEL XDK.  It builds fine and runs great on my android phones, but I'm using 4.2.

When I had users try it, any of those using 2.3.6 android releases would have a "parsing error" when they tried to install it.

According to a forum from Crosswalk where someone asked this question the answer was:  Crosswalk supports android 2.3.6 through current versions - if you have a problem on an earlier version it is due to a bug in your software.  However I have scoured the code & can't find any error.

The same code for the app runs using the cordova build options on all the versions, it's just crosswalk is clearly faster.

Does anyone have any thoughts on possible types of "coding errors" that could cause this -- if this is what is going on?  I don't get errors via the chrome js debugger or jslint.

Thanks ;)

Comment: do you mean install crosswalk based application into Android 2.3.6 devices?  that won't work since crosswalk only supports Android 4.0 and higher.

Comment: --- oh, wow I based that on a forum but just looked at the crosswalk-project.org site & you are right.  Thanks for the correction ;)